# USB webcam streaming in ARM board (i.MX6)

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer, embedded-linux, webcam, imx6

I want to streaming the camera via NETWORK. I have connected the USB webcam to i.MX6 board and want to stream in Ubuntu14.04/16.04 via network.

Incidentally, I have installed the gstreamer and ffmpeg tools for this in i.MX6 board.

Also I am able to stream USB webcam within Ubuntu14.04 PC using the following ffmpeg commands. But it's also not working if I use ffplay in other Ubuntu16.04 and I am not sure why (both are same ffmpeg versions).

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 -preset ultrafast -vcodec libx264 -tune zerolatency -b 900k -f mpegts udp://192.168.0.37:1234

ffplay udp://192.168.0.37:1234
```

**Ubuntu 16.06: (NOT WORKING)**

```
tus@titus-PC:~/workdir$ ffplay udp://192.168.0.105:1234
ffplay version 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2003-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
    nan    :  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0
```

**Ubuntu 14.04:  (WORKING)**

```
titus@titus-laptop:~$ 
titus@titus-laptop:~$ ffplay udp://127.0.0.1:1234
ffplay version 3.3.2 Copyright (c) 2003-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)
  configuration: --extra-libs=-ldl --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --mandir=/usr/share/man --enable-avresample --disable-debug --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=amrwb --enable-libpulse --enable-libfreetype --enable-gnutls --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-avisynth --enable-libsoxr --enable-libxvid --enable-libvidstab --enable-libwavpack --enable-nvenc
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libavresample   3.  5.  0 /  3.  5.  0
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
[h264 @ 0xb0621660] non-existing PPS 0 referenced sq=    0B f=0/0   
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0xb0621660] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0xb0621660] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0xb0621660] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0xb0621660] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0xb0621660] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0xb0621660] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0xb0621660] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0xb0621660] no frame!
[h264 @ 0xb0621660] non-existing PPS 0 referenced sq=    0B f=0/0   
1751.47 M-V: -0.021 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=   11KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
1751.63 M-V: -0.020 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=   11KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
1751.80 M-V: -0.020 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=   11KB sq=    0B f=0/0
```

Finally I want to stream with different ARM boards. Am also not able to build ffplay command. Same issue with raspberry pi too. I am doing something wrong or misunderstood something here?

Comment: looks a bit like a firewall issue.
perhaps adding the `?broadcast=1` option can mitigate
docs are [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#udp)

Comment: Not working. ffplay udp://192.168.0.105:1234?broadcast=1

Comment: the flag should be added i meant adding it to the ffmpeg command

Answer (score 0):

You want to stream the live USB camera feed from iMX6 to PC. Assuming I understood correctly, running the following pipeline on iMX6

```
gst-launch-1.0 imxv4l2src device=/dev/video3 ! videoconvert ! queue ! vpuenc_h264 ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=10.18.0.125 port=5004
```

and by running the following pipeline on my PC

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5004 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, payload=(int)96, encoding-name=(string)H264" ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! xvimagesink
```

I can view the USB camera stream on PC.